# How to enlarge footer on mobile only?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I have a footer at the bottom of my page. It has the following HTML and CSS:

```
<style>
    html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        /* Margin bottom by footer height */
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
    }
</style>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="container col-md-3 text-center">
        <p class="text-muted">© 2015, LuMa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="container col-md-3 text-center">
        <p><a href="/terms">Terms</a> & <a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This looks good on desktop:
[image]

But on mobile devices there is a line break:
[image]

That's okay, but how can I enlarge my footer on mobile devices? I'm not very familiar with CSS, but I heard there is a way to apply different styles on different sized devices. Has someone got a hint for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Media Queries at the end of your CSS to target your `footer` when a certain resolution is detected.

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #footer {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

This will override the footer's height when a maximum width of `480px` is detected from the screen.

[Here](http://spirelightmedia.com/resources/responsive-design-device-resolution-reference)'s a great reference list of resolutions.

[More about Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 #footer {
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/*@1 14em
mobile
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 14em) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 27em) {

}
/*
Laptops
This is the average viewing window. So Desktops, Laptops, and
in general anyone not viewing on a mobile device. Here's where
you can add resource intensive styles.
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
}
/*@2 38em
DESKTOP
This is the average viewing window. So Desktops, Laptops, and
in general anyone not viewing on a mobile device. Here's where
you can add resource intensive styles.
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 51em){

}

/* @3 51em
LARGE VIEWING SIZE
This is for the larger monitors and possibly full screen viewers.
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1240px) {

}
```

For mobile you need to enlarge height.